# Synonym for AIDS/HIV-positive?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, slang, medical

Looking for a single word, an adjective, that means "HIV-positive" or "having AIDS".

I am especially looking for slang/informal equivalents, but open to all suggestions.

**Edit:**

I am translating a text that was written when much less was known about the disease, so the lines were blurrier. The text is also about a very marginalized community, where you went from being HIV-positive to having AIDS much faster than in, say, the US or much of Europe -- the blurriness of the language also reflects that.

I should also mention that words I'm translating ("sidada" and "sidosa") are derived from the acronym "SIDA" (AIDS) but often were used by this community to mean HIV-positive.

To a certain extent, I am looking for pejorative terms, but pejorative in the sense that "queer" was pejorative and then taken back through positive usage by the community itself.

Comment: *HIV-positive* and *having AIDS* are not equivalent. See [this article](http://sfaf.org/hiv-info/basics/what-is-difference-between-hiv-aids.html?referrer=https://www.google.com/)

Comment: I agree with @bib.  HIV-positive means you've got the virus and you can transmit it, irrespective of having developed AIDS or not.  I believe any slang-word or non-medical term (if there is any) would be pejorative.

Comment: Yes, of course. I am translating a text that was written when much less was known about the disease, so the lines were blurrier. The text is also about a very marginalized community, where you went from being HIV-positive to having AIDS much faster than in, say, the US or much of Europe -- the blurriness of the language also reflects that.

Comment: If indeed you are looking for more of a pejorative term, then, provided HIV or AIDS has been mentioned to give it context, then simply **infected** could fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One colloquial/slang term that has been commonly used in the gay community for at least the past 15 or so years (though I'm not sure how widespread it was in the earlier stages of the HIV epidemic back in the ’80s) is [***poz***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Poz) (short for *HIV-**pos**itive*).

I believe it was originally at least somewhat derogatory and used especially by non-infected people; but nowadays, I'd say it is used mostly by HIV-positive people as an embraced term to identify with.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't one *good* word for this.  I would stick with a noun, but here is the closest adjective I found:

> [**Immunodeficient**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immunodeficient) **-** incapable of developing an immune response following exposure to an antigen

Keep in mind, HIV is short for the Human Immunodeficiency Virus.

Comment: Useful, thanks. Perhaps the way to go is to play with individual words like "immune," "virus" etc.